# $|V| = n$, and $|E| = n+k$, with exactly $k+1$ cycles, then the graph $G$ is connected

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I went into this problem when I was trying to prove that for all graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and no less than $n+k$ edges, it has at least $k+1$ cycles. ---**(1)**

In this question, there is no assumption of connected. What I was thinking about is do an induction on $k$, but $k$ does not goes to natural numbers, but is bounded by $n!$.

At the last step of my induction step, I was trying to prove that **if number of vertices $|V| = n$, and $|E| = n+k$, with exactly $k+1$ cycles, then the graph $G$ is connected.** ---**(2)**

I couldn't think of a proof for the bold statement, and not quite sure if it is correct. Any suggestion of approaching to (1) and (2) would help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure how you got that as the inductive step because it is a false statement: just consider a graph that only has n/2 vertices connected, then you can pack whatever you want in there. As for the original problem, you dont need induction. Think of a tree, it has n-1 edges and it is connected, now adding any more edges to it creates a cycle... can you finish from here?

Comment: @Sandeep Silwal Hi. For the first case, with n/2 vertices connected, is the graph having exactly +1  cycles? I tried some examples, but it seems that they don't satisfy the cycle number. For the suggestion of the original problem, the one you are proposing is for all connected graph. However, if we have a disconnected graph, it could still satisfies statement (1). (e.g. |V| = 5, |E| = 5, k=0, with four vertices connected while one vertex disconnected from others.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show that $G$ must be connected as follows: Let $S$ be a minimum-cardinality set of edges so that $G \setminus S$ has no cycles. Then note the following: As $G$ has exactly $k$ cycles, $|S|$ is no larger than $k$. Thus $G \setminus S$ is a graph on $n$ vertices with no cycles and at least $n-1$ edges.

We claim that $G$ has *exactly* $n-1$ edges, as every graph $G$ on $n$ vertices with $n$ or more edges has a cycle.

However, all graphs $G$ on $n$ vertices, with $n-1$ edges, and no cycles are trees, and thus connected.

Comment: Thank you! This help a lot. I just have one thing that not sure of, for the statement, "As  has exactly  cycles, || is no larger than . ", can we say  ||  is no larger than   because we can remove at least one cycle by removing one edge, therefore we can remove at most   edges?

Comment: Yes. If you remove an edge $e$ from a cycle, you destroy that cycle and in fact every cycle containing $e$--there may be more than one such cycle that contains $e$.